# Where did my "Default Group" preference go?

Tags: iphone, ios

In iOS 4.x.x, I remember having a preference in:

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Contacts

that would allow me to select a Default Group.

Now that I've upgraded to iOS 5, that preference is no longer visible.

Was it removed?  Moved?  Do I have to have a specific setup in order to have that preference available?

I need to select a "Default Group" in order to reproduce a bug reported by a beta tester, so it'd be handy to be able to set this preference.

Comment: Was the bug reported by a beta tester not yet on iOS 5?

Comment: Actually, the weird thing is that it was reported by someone on iOS 5.  In their settings, they had the option to set a "Default Group" for their Contacts, but I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 5.1, you can define a "Default Account" for Contacts in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars.  Scroll down until you see a Contacts heading; Default Account is at the bottom of that section. This setting will affect where new Contacts created on the iPhone are placed.

Comment: awesome, looks like it came back in 5.1!